# Function in select() method

Tags: javascript, html, select, d3.js

in this project i'm making an interactive periodic table, it's based from a csv file. I created a group g and i gave for each chemical elements an id. For example:

```
<g id="element1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen"><rect x="0" y="0" rx="4" ry="4" id="Nonmetal" class="xpos bordered" width="51" height="61" style="fill: rgb(255, 215, 0);"></rect></g>
```

I plot the cards for each element but now a try to add the text. In the select method i put a function to represent every elements but it doesn't work. Is it allowed to put a function in select()? Or is there another to do this?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'AtomicNumber' of
>   undefined

```
var newlist = function(csvFile){
      d3.csv(csvFile,function(d){
        return {
          AtomicNumber: d.AtomicNumber,
          Element:      d.Element,
          Symbole:      d.Symbole,
          ....
          DisplayRow: d.DisplayRow,
          DisplayColumn: d.DisplayColumn,};
      },

    function(error,data) {
      var cards = svg.selectAll(".DisplayRow")
                     .data(data, function(d) {
                       return d.DisplayRow+':'+d.DisplayColumn;
                     });
{


      cards.enter()
           .append('g')
           .attr("id",function(d) {return "element"+(d.AtomicNumber)})
           .append("rect")
           .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.DisplayColumn - 1) * (gridSize + espacecases); })                          
           .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.DisplayRow - 1) * (gridSize + 10 + espacecases); })  
           .attr("width", gridSize) 
           .attr("height", gridSize+10)
}) ;
}

{
       d3.select("body").select(function(d) {return ("#element"+d.AtomicNumber);}) 
         .append("text")
         .style("font-size",10)
         .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.DisplayColumn - 1) * (gridSize + espacecases)+10; })
         .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.DisplayRow - 1) * (gridSize + 10 + espacecases)+10; })
         .style("text-anchor", "middle")
         .text(function(d) { return (d.AtomicNumber) ; });
}
```

Comment: Another way to do it would be to wrap the code block in `cards.each(function (d) {...}` and then use `d3.select("body").select(("#element"+d.AtomicNumber))`, or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `text` in the `g` with your `rect`.  Also, you should position the `g` and then position the elements relative to the `g`.  Something like this:

```
var g = cards.enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr("id",function(d) {return "element"+(d.AtomicNumber)})
  .attr("transform", function(d){
    var x = (d.DisplayColumn - 1) * (gridSize + espacecases),
        y = (d.DisplayRow - 1) * (gridSize + 10 + espacecases);
    return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
  });

g.append("rect")
  .attr("width", gridSize) 
  .attr("height", gridSize+10);

g.append("text")
 .text(function(d){
   return (d.AtomicNumber);
 });
```